# Record audio and microphone stream as different MediaRecorder tracks at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I'm trying to record the user's response (via microphone) to some audio content, such that I can analyse the client-side timing of the user's response to this audio in an precise way. Ideally, I'd record two tracks along the same timeline: (1) the microphone stream from the user; and (2) the audio stream as heard by the user.

I am not experienced with the Web Audio API, but using some previous SO answers I arrived at the solution below: I connect the audio source (`source`) and microphone source (`stream`) in a single stream (`combinedStream`), which is fed to a `MediaRecorder`.

My questions:

1. This records a *single* track (i.e. the audio and microphone signals must be separate using post-processing). Is it possible to record them into two tracks? e.g. crudely as the two channels of a stereo signal?
2. It is not clear to me whether this is the most latency-sensitive approach, maybe there is a overhead associated with connecting the streams, or an un-captured latency associated with the actual audio playback for the client? Any advice would be appreciated - currently there is a ~10-20ms latency between audio source and playback (measured crudely by looking at the delay between audio stream and playback through speakers, as picked up on microphone stream).
3. I don't know much about HTML5 Audio, but maybe there is a better solution using it?

Thanks!

```
      ...

      // Audio for playback
      var source = context.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = ...
      source.connect(context.destination);

      // Merge audio source with microphone stream
      const mediaStreamDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
      const sourceMic = jsPsych.pluginAPI.audioContext().createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      sourceMic.connect(mediaStreamDestination);
      source.connect(mediaStreamDestination);
      let combinedStream = new MediaStream([...mediaStreamDestination.stream.getAudioTracks()]);
      
      // Media recorder
      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(combinedStream);
      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
        chunks.push(event.data);
      };

      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To record two different audio sources on two different channels (e.g right and left in a stereo file), you can use a [ChannelMergerNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelMergerNode).

Basically it's the same setup as yours, except that when connecting both sources you'd set the output channel from the `connect( destination, input_channel, output_channel )` method:

Using two oscillators:

```js
onclick = ()=>{
  onclick = null;
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  const osc1 = ctx.createOscillator();
  const osc2 = ctx.createOscillator();
  osc1.frequency.value = 300;
  osc1.start(0);
  osc2.start(0);

  const merger = ctx.createChannelMerger();
  const dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
  merger.connect( dest );

  osc1.connect( merger, 0, 0 );
  osc2.connect( merger, 0, 1 );

  // for nodes to output sound in Chrome
  // they need to be connected to the destination
  // ...
  const mute = ctx.createGain();
  mute.gain.value = 0;
  mute.connect( ctx.destination );
  osc1.connect( mute );
  osc2.connect( mute );

  const chunks = [];
  const rec = new MediaRecorder( dest.stream );
  rec.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data)
  rec.onstop = e => {
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( chunks ) );
  };
  rec.start();
  setTimeout( () => rec.stop(), 5000 );
  log.remove();
};
```

```html
<p id="log">click to start recording of 5s sample</p>
<audio id="output" controls></audio>
```

[And as a fiddle using gUM](https://jsfiddle.net/v8sbf4cp/)

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks! I have incorporated this change and it works well. Other than adjusting constraints to minimise latency (e.g. disabling `echoCancellation`, `noiseSuppression` etc), do you have any impression as to how this solution peforms compared to others?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MediaRecorder doesn't do this, at least [not in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571671).

[MediaSourceExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) does allow control over the playing of multiple tracks from inside Matroska files. webm is a subset of Matroska. The current version of the [webm standard](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/) does not allow multiple tracks. But [MSE](https://gingertech.net/2011/05/01/html5-multi-track-audio-or-video/) can play them.

It's conceivable you could use two MediaRecorders, then write code using [ebml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebml) code to crack both Matroska container and combine them into one output Matroska data stream with multiple tracks.  That is a nontrivial programming task.

Comment: Thanks! Potentially I wasn't clear in my question, is the 'track' here different in definition to the 'channel' as per the answer from @kaiido? I'm completely clueless when it comes to "ebml", I'll check it out!